# "unrecognized selector" which does not exist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, selector

I hit a problem in an iPhone app where it crashes, displaying the following message in the debugger console:

> 2012-08-31 12:31:24.628 test_app[1672:207] -[My_ViewController
>   tapDetected:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7621ef0

The strange thing is that "tapDetected" does not even exist anymore in my code for this class. It used to be a method, but it has been removed and replaced by a different one.

I noticed though that when I look at the .xib file, in the first responder, "tapDetected" still appears in the list.
But I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem or not, and I do not see any way to remove it.

Any idea or suggestion about this issue will be welcome.

Comment: So what makes it crash? Pressing a button? On launch? On loading of the view?

Comment: search tapDetected in entire project and remove it also check this method might be binded with UIElememts used in project

Comment: Is anything connected to "tapDetected" in the xib ?

Comment: The fact is, there is no button firing "tapDetected", but it was fired by a UITapGestureRecognizer object allocated programmatically.
In the code there used to be:
 _tapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];_
but this has been replaced by:
 _sndTapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sndTapDetected:)];_

Comment: I have checked both within IB and in my code. I cannot figure out what is trying to fire this "tapDetected".

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I finally found the problem. I was trying to fire the dam method from another (remote) part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Remove tapDetected: method from .xib from where it is calling.

Answer (score 0):

Open your .xib file. Select the button in your .xib file which generated the error. Select **Show Utilities**=>Click on **Connection Inspector**=>Check the **Sent Events** list. Remove the connection to tapDetected: if exits.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the button in xib (which i am guessing gives the error when pressed) is still connected to the method..in ur xib file..just delete that connection from the connection inspector list for that button..

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that when you deal with interface builder stuff and xib files, sometimes your app can also crash regardless of making sure you deleted something from your xib file.

I learnt that this was cause because the previous copy of the app on the simulator is somehow "caching" the xib contents.

The fix was to delete the instance of the app from the simulator or device, then re-run the app again.